# Find the error - initial value problem

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> Find a local solution for the following initial value problem $$y' = (y+1)^3, \qquad y(0)=0$$

---

I have approached this using separation of variables and obtained

$$y=\sqrt{-\frac{1}{2x-1}}-1$$

locally, of course. However, differentiating this yields

$$y'=\left(\frac{1}{-2x+1} \right)^{2.5}$$

which doesn't solve the general differential equation above. What have I done wrong?

**Edit:** Added the computation of $y'$:

$$y'=\frac{1}{2}\left( -\frac{1}{2x-1} \right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\left((-2x+1)^{-1} \right)'=\frac{1}{2}\left( -\frac{1}{2x-1}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\cdot 2\cdot (-2x+1)^{-2}=\frac{1}{(-2x+1)^{2.5}}$$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yes, that's true but I thought that whether I choose $+$ or $-$ doesn't change the exponent in the derivative.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the reply, do you know where exactly I've made the mistake because I've checked multiple times and can't seem to find it.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks but do you know in which step the mistake lies? Have I made a mistake when using the chain rule?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo But where? I don't find the incorrect step. I've simply applied the chain rule, it looks.

Answer (score 1):

Using [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org):

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = Symbol('x', real=True)
>>> f = (1 / sqrt(1 - 2 * x)) - 1
>>> diff(f,x)
(1 - 2*x)**(-3/2)
```

Hence,

$$f ' (x) = \frac{1}{\left(1 - 2 x\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

while you computed

$$f ' (x) = \frac{1}{\left(1 - 2 x\right)^{\frac{5}{2}}}$$

Comment: My computation looks correct though..

Comment: Note that $-\frac12 - 1 = ?$

Comment: $-\frac{3}{2}$ but that doesn't appear in the computation of the derivative

Comment: Of course it does. Look at the output of `diff`.

Comment: Thanks for asking, actually no, since I still don't know what exactly I did wrong in the computation of the above derivative.

Answer (score 0):

The constant solution $y=-1$ can be ruled out because of the initial condition. Any other solution is given implicitly by
$$
\int \frac{1}{(y+1)^3} dy = \int dx \Leftrightarrow \frac{(y+1)^{-2}}{-2} = x + C
$$

since $y(0)=0$, we get $C=-\frac 12$, which means that
$$
\frac{1}{(y+1)^2} = -2x+1\Leftrightarrow (y+1)^2 = \frac{1}{-2x+1}\Leftrightarrow y = -1 + \sqrt{\frac{1}{-2x+1}}
$$

This function (which you also obtained) solves the differential equation.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but that results in $y'=\left( \frac{1}{-2x+1} \right)^{2.5}$, doesn't it? That was exactly my problem.

Comment: @user what you need to do is  checking  if $y'=(y+1)^3$... You are not computing $y'$ correctly.

Comment: I've added my computation, do you maybe know where my mistake lies?